# Do I need to run Webrick before running Cucumber with Selenium?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, selenium, cucumber, capybara

If I'm using cucumber/capybara with a selenium web driver to test, do I need to open up the rails server in a separate terminal before executing cucumber?

(Presently I am running it with the server open but I am getting 'database is locked' errors from sqlite, which I believe is cucumber and webrick clashing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need an active Rails server to run Cucumber tests, and having a running server (Webrick, Mongrel, etc) should not effect your DB unless you are running off of the same DB for test and dev. The testing suites spin up their own copy of rails and should use the "AppName-Test" (by default) database for the testing.

The database locked, is that happening on the first test, or later on in testing? If its later in testing, you might have a lager DB transaction that is in progress as you move in to the next test. If you think this is the case, throw a 'sleep 30' at the end of the first test to check... give the DB some time to cool down. If that fixes it, look in the code for anything that runs abnormally long DB transactions.

A good gem to augment testing would be:
https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner

It should help kill any DB test interaction. Hopefully, this can get you going on the right path.

Comment: You're right, this seems to work better. It is happening on the first test; it seems the transaction won't complete, but it's only a couple of small inserts so I shouldn't imagine it's taking too long. Is there anything else that could cause it to get stuck?

Comment: reset your test db `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:reset` I believe... (If thats not the one, do a `rake -T` to see the tasks and ind a DB one that does a reset - db:drop and db:setup could have to be run). If doing a fresh start on the test DB doesn't work, check the inserts in a visual test: Spin up the rails server, do what your test does in your browser, then watch what the console says is going on. Maybe you can get an indication of the hang in there.

Comment: For anyone else getting these errors, check that database cleaner is set to truncation for sqlite- seems to work better.